# File corruption in windows Opertaing sytem after power failure

Tags: c++, windows, file, visual-c++

Below operation happens very frequently in our application ,whenever power failure happens dest.xml will be corrupted and i see only NULNULNULNULNUL when opened with Notepad++ . I have tried  disabling cache and using combination of remove() and rename() for renaming src.xml.ignore to dest.xml . Still the same issue .Is there any way to resolve this problem during power failure

```
MemoryOutputStream file;
file << dir << '\\' << relPath << idToUse << ".xml.ignore";
CSString temp = file.AsString(); /* CSString is our  internalstring class it can be converted into const char* */
FileUtils::MakeDirsInFilePath( temp );

static const int NUM_RETRIES = 50;
static const int WAIT_AMT = 100;

int i;
for ( i = 0; i < NUM_RETRIES; ++i )
{
    FILE * fp = ::_fsopen( temp, "wb", _SH_DENYRW );
    if ( fp != 0 )
    {
        FileOutputStream fos( fp, true );
        fos << xml;
        if ( fos.Close() )
        {
            break;
        }

        FileUtils::Delete( temp );
    }
    Thread::SleepFor( WAIT_AMT );
}
if ( i == NUM_RETRIES )
{
    return false;
}

// move into place
//
file.Reset();
file << dir << '\\' << idToUse << ".xml";
CSString dest = file.AsString();

DWORD flags = MOVEFILE_COPY_ALLOWED|MOVEFILE_WRITE_THROUGH;
if (overwrite) flags |= MOVEFILE_REPLACE_EXISTING;
BOOL rc = ::MoveFileEx( src, dest, flags ); ///Dest file is getting corrupted
```

Comment: What behaviour are you wanting instead?

Comment: Invest in  a UPS.

Comment: Problem is our software is used by one of our customer who does not have UPS . We want either 0 or 1 like solution either MovefileEx should rename it without any issues or it should not happen (atomic) .

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect us to help with, if the power goes off, everything stops running and the state is not saved and whatever was or was not written out the to hard drive is what is there (i.e. you can't `try`/`catch` a power loss).

Comment: You would need a [journaling file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journaling_file_system), but securing the power supply would be much easier.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525943/cause-of-corrupted-file-contents

Answer (score -2):

You need to use synchronous IO, which means you're going to have to use the Windows API instead of `FILE` and `fopen`.

I haven't done Windows programming n years, but a quick Google search suggests you'll want to use [`CreateFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx) (I'm guessing the `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` and `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` flags, but that's going of ctrl+f).  Once you have the file handle, use [`WriteFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365747(v=vs.85).aspx)